# Cannot see WebdriverIO logs in the console (webdriver logs)

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io, wdio-v5

I am using WebdriverIO version 5 and would like to see the logs of my test run.

I tried the command: `npm run rltest --logLevel=info`, but all I can see is the output of the spec reporter.

```
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 Mac OS X #0-0] Running: chrome (v83.0.4103.116) on Mac OS X
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 Mac OS X #0-0] Session ID: 16d526a6b3cc51f54110024b112b247c
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 Mac OS X #0-0]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 Mac OS X #0-0] cancel button
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 Mac OS X #0-0]    ✓ Verify that when the user clicks on the Cancel 
button, no changes made to the list
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 Mac OS X #0-0]
[chrome 83.0.4103.116 Mac OS X #0-0] 1 passing (36.2s)
```

Is there a way to see more detailed logs? Do I need to configure anything inside `wdio.conf.js`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check documentation - [logLevel](https://webdriver.io/docs/options.html#loglevel)

So basically you need to setup this property in `wdio.conf.js`:

```
 // ===================
  // Test Configurations
  // ===================
  // Define all options that are relevant for the WebdriverIO instance here
  //
  // Level of logging verbosity: trace | debug | info | warn | error | silent
  logLevel: 'debug',
```

Comment: or different log level - debug is very detail. It is up to you and you need to try :)

Answer (score 1):

You should see the `wdio` logs in your console, as WebdriverIO defaults to dumping all the Selenium logs into `stdout`. Hope I understood correctly and you're talking about the `webdriver` logs, as below:

```
[0-0] 2020-07-01T09:28:53.869Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/933eeee4135ea0ca37d57f0b807cb29e/element/0.45562246642229964-9/displayed
[0-0] 2020-07-01T09:28:53.878Z INFO webdriver: RESULT true
[0-0] 2020-07-01T09:28:53.879Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND findElement("css selector", "#_evidon-l3 button")
[0-0] 2020-07-01T09:28:53.879Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/session/933eeee4135ea0ca37d57f0b807cb29e/element
[0-0] 2020-07-01T09:28:53.879Z INFO webdriver: DATA { using: 'css selector', value: '#_evidon-l3 button' }
[0-0] 2020-07-01T09:28:53.888Z INFO webdriver: RESULT { ELEMENT: '0.45562246642229964-10' }
[0-0] 2020-07-01T09:28:53.889Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND isElementDisplayed("0.45562246642229964-10")
```

If this is not the case, please check if you have `outputDir` option set inside the `wdio.conf.js` file. If indeed you have this setup, then you are overriding the default, sending the log streams to files inside that path:

e.g: `outputDir: 'wdio-logs',` (`wdio.conf.js` file)

[image]

The logs should be inside the `wdio-x-y.log` files. So, either debug your cases using the overridden path log files, or remove `outputDir` entry from your `wdio.conf.js` file if you want them inside the console.

---

Even better, you could be fancy and set `outputDir: process.env.CONSOLELOGS ? null : 'wdio/logs/path/here'`. Then you can run your checks with a system variable to trigger console logging:

`CONSOLELOGS=true npm run rltest <params>`

Comment: You understood it correctly. i would like to see the logs in the stdout. I don't have outputDir set on my configuration file. not sure why i am not able to see it. i noticed the even a simple console.log won't output anything in the stdout. maybe it can be something with the allure reporter?

Comment: No, it shouldn't affect your logging, as allure has it's own `outputDir` path for logging. As for the `outputDir` value inside the `wdio.conf.js` file, just add it inside the object and set the path where you want the webdriver logs to be streamed to.

Comment: Maybe the value gets overwritten somewhere, you can also try to give it `outputDir: null` and try to force the default `stdout` logging.